# Interpreting Matlab Fitln

Tags: matlab, linear-regression

I have a series of 200 x/y data-points and am using matlab to generate a model. I am trying to determine of what order the polynomial function generated by fitln should be. I tried starting at 6, hoping that some higher-order coefficients wouldn't be significant, but get the following:

```
Linear regression model:
    y ~ 1 + x1 + x1^2 + x1^3 + x1^4 + x1^5 + x1^6

Estimated Coefficients:
                    Estimate          SE         tStat       pValue  
                   ___________    __________    _______    __________

    (Intercept)              0             0        NaN           NaN
    x1                   11897         462.8     25.706    2.1825e-64
    x1^2               -442.92        26.689    -16.596     4.438e-39
    x1^3                 7.323       0.55975     13.083    1.8862e-28
    x1^4             -0.059949     0.0053902    -11.122     1.516e-22
    x1^5            0.00023784    2.4198e-05     9.8286    9.3122e-19
    x1^6           -3.6511e-07    4.1034e-08    -8.8978    4.0169e-16


Number of observations: 201, Error degrees of freedom: 195
Root Mean Squared Error: 1.36e+04
R-squared: 0.519,  Adjusted R-Squared 0.506
F-statistic vs. constant model: 42, p-value = 3.1e-29
```

I get the following with a polynomial of order 5:

```
Linear regression model:
    y ~ 1 + x1 + x1^2 + x1^3 + x1^4

Estimated Coefficients:
                    Estimate          SE         tStat       pValue  
                   ___________    __________    _______    __________

    (Intercept)     1.0011e+05        19.058     5252.9             0
    x1                  -19.02        1.3004    -14.626    3.0955e-33
    x1^2               0.27502      0.026087     10.542    7.1559e-21
    x1^3            -0.0029912    0.00019381    -15.434    1.0751e-35
    x1^4           -2.1979e-06    4.7601e-07    -4.6174    7.0203e-06


Number of observations: 201, Error degrees of freedom: 196
Root Mean Squared Error: 52.4
R-squared: 1,  Adjusted R-Squared 1
F-statistic vs. constant model: 5.8e+05, p-value = 0
```

Now, I noticed that in all cases p values are very low (good, I suppose) and R-squared is greater than 0.5 (which I assume is also good).

So, I am not really sure what to make of this data. I know that I should aim for lower-order polynomials, but how can I justify this?

Comment: Usually you want to minimize the **Root Mean Squared Error (RMSE)**. In your case, order 5 has a lower RMSE, so it is "better". I'd try to go even lower in order, since the coefficient of x⁴ is rather small. You could also use `cftool` to visualize your fittings. Aside from that, do you have any knowledge of the underlying analytical phenomena which produce your datapoints?

Comment: Hi @m.s., thanks, order 2 yields a lower RMSE than both 1 and 3. This is unsurprising as from visual inspection it clearly is the best way of modelling the relation. However, I needed a more formal way of justifying this than "it looks a polynomial of order 2". I'm having some difficulties understanding the actual meaning of RMSE, would you have any resources you could point to?

Comment: Have a look at the [least squares method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares) which is related to the RMSE.